# Handling negation in words

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of strings like

```
I don’t like this book
```

And I need something like below. How would I obtain this

```
I do not like this book
```

Comment: You need a dictionary for replacement. And you don't need regular expressions. Regular expressions are used to search (yes, I know about `re.sub`). Just use `str.replace`.

Comment: I can't think of an English word that wouldn't work with a straight "n't" replacement to " not"

Comment: @sberry: "won't", "shan't", "ain't".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
replacement = {"n't": " not", "book":"notebook"}
string = raw_input("Enter your sentence: ")

for rplc in replacement:
    string = string.replace(rplc, replacement[rplc])

print string
```

Works as below:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter your sentence: This isn't a book
This is not a notebook
>>>
```

Add everything you want replaced to the `replacement` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need use `replace` and `dict` to specify the options. You can easily expand the dictionary. Will be replaced by the words beginning with a capital letter.:

```
replace_dict = {
    "don't": "do not",
    "won't": "will not",
    "didn't": "did not",
    "doesn't": "does not"
}

def replace_word(text):
    for word in replace_dict:
        if word in text:  # Small first letter
            text = text.replace(word, replace_dict[word])
        elif word[0].title() + word[1:] in text:  # Big first letter
            text = text.replace(word[0].title() + word[1:],
                                replace_dict[word][0].title() + replace_dict[word][1:])

    return text

print replace_word("Don't go")
```

`>>> I do not go`

Comment: Small case works for me . I don't think i would land in elif condition. Thanks